# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in, when change mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, fatal-error

I have this class for mysql connection and I want to replace it to mysqli without changed functions name.

```
class DB { function DB($db_host, $db_user, $db_port, $db_pass, $db_name) {

$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die("Can't connect to database");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
}    
public static function execute($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not query:$sql");
    return $result;
}   
public static function num_rows($result)
{
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

public static function fetch($result)
{
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
}

$DB = new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PORT, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

I tried to change something but have a problem with constructor $link (can't put to execute function). Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

```
class DB {
function DB($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass,$db_name) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

     return $link;          
}    
public static function execute($sql) {

             //$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '' , 'database');

$this->DB(); 

$result = mysqli_query(**$link**,$sql); 

    return $result;
}
public static function num_rows($result)
{
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

public static function fetch($result)
{
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
}
```

How I can use constructor $link in execute function??? 
Somebody can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't use `$this` in static functions. You need to make `$link` a static variable.

Comment: Do you realize that your class is extremely insecure and consists of essential flaws?

Comment: No, what is a problem? Can you help me? I need class with mysqli connection

Comment: Why are you writing your own ORM when there's already several like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/) already written?

Comment: I have this class in my CMS and many sites working with It. I want to replace mysql to mysqli for avoiding further problems

Answer (score 0):

That is because `$this` keyword is not accesible on a static context.

Change your function definition like this.

from

```
public static function execute($sql) {
```

to

```
public function execute($sql) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PDO for these operations, don't try to rewrite it ;)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And since PHP5, a constructor is declared like this : __construct()